# Which manga authors have said to be inspired by Akira Toriyama?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

If I've read correctly, the creators of One Piece and Naruto have said at some point to be inspired by Akira Toriyama or Dragon Ball. Are there others important manga authors who have said the same?

Which manga authors have said to be inspired by Akira Toriyama?

Comment: I think in one way or another, practically all the shonen manga authors after 90s got some influence (at least talking about authors creating battle-ish manga).

Comment: This is at least curious because sometimes you see Naruto or One Piece fans bashing Dragon Ball, but their authors have said to be inspired by it

Answer (score 2):

Most of the big Shonen Jump creators, including Eiichiro Oda, Masashi Kishimoto, Hiro Mashima, Mikio Ikemoto, Atsushi Suzumi, and Tite Kubo, but I think all of them have held their respect and gained inspiration since his death.